# Automatically randomize rotation for each duplicated object

Tags: transforms, random

Is there any way to randomize the rotation on z-axis of an object each time I duplicate it?

The *Randomize Transform* feature doesn't work for me, because it needs to be done manually every single time I re-arrange the scene. Maybe it can be done with geo-nodes/drivers/etc?

[image]

Comment: The "Randomize Transform" operator can operate on multiple objects at once, so if you duplicate it as many times as you need, then you will only "Randomize Transform" once and the effect will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this node setup to achieve your effect:

[image]

this is for sure not the most elegant way to do it - but it works.

[image]

Comment: this is perfect! and genius! thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome